# Meaning of 率いる in the following sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, manga, sports

Context: in a manga, a boxer is talking about the president of a boxing gym. What is the meaning of 率いる in the following sentence? I know it means `to lead` or `to command`, but I don't think it is the exact meaning here. Could it be similar to `to train` or `to guide` in this case? (I split the sentence as it is in the manga)

> 何せ会長は… / / 世界・日本ベルト保持者複数を率いるジムの責任者… / / 結果出せる選手しか相手できないですからね。

My translation attempt:

> If the president is the manager of a gym that trains (?) many World and
>   Japanese title holders, it is because they can only fight boxers that
>   achieved good results.

Also, could you help me understand the general meaning of the sentence? What it means is that the many boxers of this gym won a title because the president forced them to fight only the strongest opponents? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 率いる is "to lead" in the sense of managing/guiding as a leader/head. It does not mean "to train". For example you can say 50人の従業員を率いる印刷会社の社長, 山田先生が率いるクラス.

Anyway your understanding of the whole sentence is not spot-on. 相手にする is "to deal with" or "to take care of" in this context. 何せ is "anyway", "at any rate" or "after all" (why "If"?). ～からね at the end is "I'm saying this (*or* You can say that) because ～" and is referring to something more distant. But it's simply used like "you know".

> 何せ、会長は世界・日本ベルト保持者複数を率いるジムの責任者。結果出せる選手しか相手できないですからね。
>   After all, the president is the manager of a gym who leads several Japanese and World champion belt holders. He can only deal with players who can achieve good results, you know.

The basic implication of the sentence is "The president is too busy to take care of players who are not promising," or may be simply "The president is not interested in weak players."

Answer (score 1):

相手にする as look after fits in the context.

Quick interpretation: Let me assume the CEO of boxing gym only does match-making. Since he is the president of many title holders of the world and those of Japan and probably has a good tradition on his gym itself, the CEO does not want to hire a boxer if he could win or not so that he might give a bad name on his gym, which always needs good results like Real Madrid in soccer or NewYork Yankees in baseball.

I interpret 結果出せる選手　as an established boxer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. I'd take 率いるto mean 'lead' in this situation, so it'd be similar to the english.

世界・日本ベルト保持者複数を率いるジムの責任者
world/Japanese belt holders - lead gym - responsibility holder.

The person responsible for leading a gym with multiple world and Japanese belts.